# Fetching value and key from local Json file in node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

Hello Everyone, I have trouble with fetching items from local json file as value and key in NodeJs.

```
[
{
"question":"What is the first name of your best friend in high school?",
"answer":"U2FsdGVkX18/l/UF1DbqMp9ItOqgmmQIeVUlxqrb7vE="},
{
"question":"What was your childhood nickname?",
"answer":"U2FsdGVkX1+x14bgpnjr3UcvScBDbIOnP55vua2NvME="},
{
"question":"What is the name of the street you grew up in?",
"answer":"U2FsdGVkX1+pGkO/MRIP7oHym3Ynz/7n/fYuEt7fTFw="}]
```

This the local json file.

How can i fetch questions and answers and save them to different arrays.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your local data file in `data.json`, you can use it like shown below.

```
var data = require('./data.json')
console.log(data[0]);
```

Comment: Won't `data` be a string and need to be parsed to JSON first?

Comment: Yeah it should be string and parsed

Comment: @JeremyThille nope. It will be parsed internally. In this case data will be a valid Json object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [
{
    "question":"What is the first name of your best friend in high school?",
    "answer":"U2FsdGVkX18/l/UF1DbqMp9ItOqgmmQIeVUlxqrb7vE="},
{
    "question":"What was your childhood nickname?",
    "answer":"U2FsdGVkX1+x14bgpnjr3UcvScBDbIOnP55vua2NvME="},
{
    "question":"What is the name of the street you grew up in?",
    "answer":"U2FsdGVkX1+pGkO/MRIP7oHym3Ynz/7n/fYuEt7fTFw="
}];

var data = JSON.parse(data); 
var questions = data.map(current =>  current.question);
var answers = data.map(current => current.answer);
```

Comment: I didn't realise it was a JSON data. We just have to parse into an object first, add this line at the beggining:

var data = JSON.parse(data);

Answer (score 0):

If your json file wants to be read from the file system it would be:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./file.json', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});
```